# Regular expression for a list of string objects

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list as following:

```
list12 = ['**FIRS0425 SOPL ZTE First Company limited', 'Apple Technology','*ROS Sami']
```

My code is as following

```
import re
[item2 for item in list12 for item2 in item.split() if not re.match("^[*A-Z]+(0-9){4}$", item2)]
```

I got output like :

```
['First', 'Company', 'limited', 'Apple', 'Technology', 'Sami']
```

I expect the output to be like :

```
['SOPL', 'ZTE', 'First', 'Company', 'limited', 'Apple', 'Technology', 'ROS', 'Sami']
```

I am not good with regular expression. How can I reach to my required solution?

Comment: Why not `**FIRS0425` ? There's a `*` as well.

Comment: You may use `if not re.match(r"\**[A-Z]+[0-9]{4}$", item2)`. Note it will output `'*ROS'`, not `'ROS'`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/K4hYaN). However, the same output can be achieved if you replace `(0-9)` with `[0-9]` in your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **non-regex** way in python,

```
list12 = ['**FIRS0425 SOPL ZTE First Company limited', 'Apple Technology','*ROS Sami']
str = " ".join(list12)
list21 = str.split()
res = [k.strip('*') for k in list21 if '**' not in k]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['SOPL', 'ZTE', 'First', 'Company', 'limited', 'Apple', 'Technology', 'ROS', 'Sami']
```

**DEMO:**  http://tpcg.io/s9aBhe

Comment: any specific reason for voting it down?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're looking for

```
\b([A-Za-z]+)\b
```

In `Python`:

```
import re
list12 = ['**FIRS0425 SOPL ZTE First Company limited', 'Apple Technology','*ROS Sami']

rx = re.compile(r'\b([A-Za-z]+)\b')
result = [word for item in list12 for word in rx.findall(item)]
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
['SOPL', 'ZTE', 'First', 'Company', 'limited', 'Apple', 'Technology', 'ROS', 'Sami']
```

Comment: This solution is similar but i have a huge text and the code which you wrote is having 2 for loops and consuming most of my time.